# How does a sequence in oracle SQL work?

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g

Lets say that i have to make 5 tables which need a number as a primary key. 
Can I use the same sequence for all these tables or do i have to create a new one for each ?
Is there a statement which 
 - finds out all the existing sequences so that we can choose one ?
 - Shows all the sequences for a particular user/particular schema ?

Comment: For all sequences - select * from user_sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one sequence for all, but if you have to insert many rows thus will be a bottleneck.  Each time one row is inserted the other inserts have to wait. I prefer to use one sequence for each table. 
As sequences are db objects you can query them from the catalog.

Comment: Nice point about the wait. Thanks :)

Comment: Sequences are designed for high concurrency.  With a sufficient cache size, I doubt you will see any performance difference between using one sequence versus using five.  I ran a quick test comparing 1 sequence versus 3 sequences, both with `cache 10000`.  There was no significant difference, both generated about 100K sequences per second.  (But it was a very simple test, I could be wrong.)